# How to count bytes using send() in C, including protocol size?

Tags: c, sockets

I'm trying to count total send bytes from my program, but I can't get accurate value.
All my functions call a single function that send data to my server using send() function.
In this function, i get return of send() and sum into global counter. This is working fine.
But when I compare to 'iftop' utility (sudo iftop -f 'port 33755'), I'm getting more data on iftop then in my app....and my guess if because of tcp headers/protocol data. I really don't know how to calculate this. I'm sending packets using send() and variable data length, so I'm not sure if is possible to detect/calculate TCP packet size from there. I know that each TCP packet send TCP header, but I'm not sure how many packets is sent.
May I assume that every call to send(), if data length is less than 1518 (TCP packet size limite?), than it's only one TCP packet and I need to sum TCP Header length? Even if I sent one byte? If so, how much is these extra-bytes from TCP structure?!

For information: I'm using GCC on linux as compiler.

Tks!

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you have already done

Comment: From your application? You can't. And why do you need the lower-level data count (which have fixed sizes and can be easily calculated)? What is the *real* problem that is supposed to solve? And how deep down do you want to go? TCP? IP? Ethernet?

Comment: Also note that TCP is a *streaming* protocol, there's no "packages" or "packets" on the application level, it's all just a stream of bytes. The data you send with a single `send` might be sent as a single Ethernet frame, or multiple. And on the receiving side you could get all the data from one `send` call with a single `recv` call, or you might need multiple `recv` calls to receive all data. Or a single `recv` call could give you data from multiple `send` calls.

Comment: On Windows you could use .NET to interface windows telling you the network statistics of your own process. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b6b43fc4-053f-44e4-9956-65a97dbc2916/c-application-for-monitoring-network-traffic-per-process?forum=csharpgeneral. On Linux you could use also an external program from within your code to monitor the traffic of your process as well. https://askubuntu.com/questions/11709/how-can-i-capture-network-traffic-of-a-single-process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to count bytes using send() in C, including protocol size?

There is no reliable way to do so from within your program.  You can compute a *minimum* total number of bytes required to transmit data of the total payload size you count, subject to a few assumptions, but you would need to monitor from the kernel side to determine the exact number of bytes.

> May I assume that every call to send(), if data length is less than
>   1518 (TCP packet size limite?), than it's only one TCP packet and I
>   need to sum TCP Header length?

No, that would not be a safe assumption.  The main problem is that the kernel does not necessarily match the data transferred by each `send()` call to its own sequence of packets.  It may combine data from multiple `send()`s into a smaller number of packets.  Additionally, however, it may use either a smaller MTU or a larger one than Ethernet's default of 1500 bytes, depending on various factors, and, furthermore, you need to fit packet headers into the chosen MTU, so the payload carried by one packet is smaller than that.

I suspect you're making this too hard.  If this is a task that has been assigned to you -- a homework problem, for example -- then my first guess would be that it is intended that you count only the total payload size, not the protocol overhead.  Alternatively, if you do need to account for the overhead, then my guess would be that you are supposed to *estimate*, based on measured or assumed characteristics of the network.  If you've set this problem for yourself, then I can only say that people generally make one of the two computations I just described, not the one you asked about.

Comment: Thanks @john, thats' very helpful. I have one box (hardware) that send data to server and I would like to estimate/calculate total bytes sent (including protocolo overhead), so user can see how much traffic is being used by this box daily/monthly/etc..that's why I' trying to calculate total bytes sent with most accurate that is possible.